# Использование config.properties в проекте

Tags: java, maven, properties

Есть проект, в котором 3 класса, которые взаимодействуют друг с другом. 4й класс - `SendProperties`, который позволяет взаимодействовать с файлом `config.properties`. Вот код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendProperties {

    private static Properties properties= new Properties(); ;


    public static String getProperty(String propertyKey) {
        if(properties.containsKey(propertyKey)) {
            return properties.getProperty(propertyKey);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void setProperties(String file) throws IOException {

        properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(file)));

    }

    public static Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Основной класс `SendJMS`. Его конструктор загружает файл:

```
 public SendJMS() {
        try {
            SendProperties.setProperties("config.properties");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

При запуске получаю `FileNotFoundException`. Хотя файл точно лежит в проекте в папке `resources`

Сделано это было для того, чтобы использовать один экземпляр файла пропертей во всех классах, а не создавать в каждом по экземпляру.

Как можно решить данную проблему? Или есть какие еще способы для того, чтобы использовать `config.properties` во всех классах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы был использован блок static в классе SendProperties

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendProperties {

    private static Properties properties = new Properties(); ;


    public static String getProperty(String propertyKey) {
        if(properties.containsKey(propertyKey)) {
            return properties.getProperty(propertyKey);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

   static {
        try {
            properties.load(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если путь не указан для файла `File` или `FileInputStream`, то подразумевается что он относительный для конечного файла.

Папка ресурсов не всегда может быть относительным путём для такого файла. Если эта папка указана на пути классов, как в большинстве проектов, которые собираются с помощью maven или gradle, то наиболее подходящий способ доступа к файлу является использование загрузчика классов.

Можно использовать `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.