# Пути к ресурсам

Tags: java, jar

Есть программа, которой нужно иногда считывать данные из файлов. В самой программе указываю путь:

```
File fileRoot = new File(".\\src\\Resources");
```

Однако, если создать jar, то программа эти папки не находит. Какой путь надо указать, чтобы программа считала эти файлы при переносе jar-файла на другой компьютер (естественно, папка Resources переносится вместе с jar)?

Включать папку в сам проект не нужно, там могут быть разные файлы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952322/204920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вы можете это сделать универсально, для файла который лежит рядом с jar:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResouceAsStram("./file.txt");
```

вот при таком размещении файлов

```
./ 
 |__ *.jar
 |__ file.txt
```

Comment: Помогло вот это:   
File fileRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Resources");